# Load the content only after switching tabs. Javascript Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

How to load content **only after switching a tab**?

Load only TAB1 at start, then only **after** clicking TAB2 or TAB3 **then load their content, but do not load them at start**

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t52mwLoc/

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">

<h4 class="card-title">Default Tab</h4>
                      
                      
                                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-selected="true">TAB1</a> </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-selected="false"> TAB2</a> </li>
                        
  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"> TAB3</a> </li>
                        
</ul>

                                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                                            <div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active show" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
                                                    <div class="p-20">
                                                        Load this content...
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane  p-20" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">Load this AFTER clicking [TAB2]</div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="tab3" role="tabpanel">Load this AFTER clicking [TAB3]</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                
                
                
                
                
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unmitigated's answer assumes that the relative ordering of the nav-items and the tab-panes are the same. I believe it is better to not assume that, and recommend using something like this, instead:

```
$('ul.nav-tabs').on('show.bs.tab', '.nav-item', function () {
    let containerSelector = $(this).children('a.nav-link').attr('href');
    let $container = $(containerSelector);
    $container.html('test');
});
```

The above sample also delegates the event to the ul rather than the nav-items themselves just in case the tabs need to change dynamically. In other words, the event doesn't need to be added to any new nav-links.

You can still use the index of the nav-link if you want to still associate that to your data, but I'd recommend associating the data to an object using the ids as keys, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the `show.bs.tab` event to load the content.

```js
// Content to load stored in array just for demonstration purposes
const content = ["Load this content...", "Load this AFTER clicking [TAB2]", "Load this AFTER clicking [TAB3]"];
$('.nav-tabs > .nav-item').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).data('loaded')) { // Don't load same content twice
    $(this).data('loaded', true).closest('.nav-tabs')
      .parent().find('.tab-pane').eq($(this).index())
      .text(content[$(this).index()]); // Or load using AJAX
  }
}).find('a.active').trigger('show.bs.tab'); 
// Trigger on initially active tab to load its content first
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Default Tab</h4>
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-selected="true">TAB1</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-selected="false"> TAB2</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> TAB3</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
        <div class="tab-pane active show" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
          <div class="p-20"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="tab2" role="tabpanel"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="tab3" role="tabpanel"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```